# getsizeof always 40 in python for each field in a csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, python-3.x, sys

So I am reading a csv file row by row. Inside each row I go field by field and try to get the size of each field in bytes suing .getsizeof. The code is below :

```
for row in reader:
        temp1 = []
        temp2 = []
        if type(row[0]) is IntType:
            feed = feed + 1
            print feed
            # Total number of columns in a feed should be 61.
            # 61st column account for the last , after 60th column, it would always be blank.
            #if len(row) == 61:
            # Total number of columns in a feed should be 61
            for field in row:
                if type(field) == 'int':
                    field.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                    temp1.append(sys.getsizeof(field))
                    temp2.append(str(field))

                else:
                    field = [unicode(field)]
                    #field = field.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                    temp1.append(sys.getsizeof(field))
                    temp2.append(str(field))
```

For some reason the size foe every field accross all rows is coming out 40. Any idea why ?

Comment: You misunderstand what `sys.getsizeof()` *does*.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` is shallow; it doesn't look into a list's contents, or an object's properties, etc, since it's hard to tell what's "part of the object" and what's just a reference to something that shouldn't be considered part of the object.

Comment: This smells like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want the sizes? What do you expect them to be, and what are you hoping to use that information for?

Answer (score 0):

First, this:

```
field.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

… doesn't actually do anything useful. It doesn't change `field`; it just returns a new `bytes` holding an ASCII-encoded version of your `field`, which you don't store anywhere.

On top of that, you only call it when your `field` is an `int`, in which case you'll get an `AttributeError`, because `int` objects don't have an `encode` method.

So, clearly, you're only hitting the `else` case. And what does that do?

Well, it makes a 1-element list. You're not asking the size of that element, but the size of the list. So, they'll all be the same size.

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) explain:

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

So, what if you want to know the size of the list, plus all 1 of its elements? A couple paragraphs down there's a general-purpose solution:

> See [recursive sizeof recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504) for an example of using `getsizeof()` recursively to find the size of containers and all their contents.

However, in your case, there's a much simpler solution: `sys.getsizeof(field) + sys.getsizeof(field[0])` will do.

But note that this may not be what you wanted anyway. For example, if you have 1000 rows, and 900 of them have the value `'0'`, you're going to count `u'0'` 900 times… but really, you're probably only actually storing one copy of `u'0'`, with 900 references to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are only getting the size of the reference instead of the size of the actually string field.